# Issue aligning images properly

Tags: html, css

I want all of the images to be centered on the page, but to also repeat one after another with margins and all that. The problem is, they are all being lined in a straight line like this: [image] when they should be going from left to right.

My HTML/CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Join the Team</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    .__applyingfor {
      width: 500px;
      height: 150px;
      margin: auto auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .__applyoptions {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .__applyoptions ul{
      display: flex;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      background-size: cover;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .__applyoptions ul li{
      margin-right: 1px;
    }

    .__applyoptions ul a{
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
    }

    .__apply-normal:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .__apply-hover {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .__apply-hover:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    #__title {
      font-size: 25px;
    }

    #__title:hover {
      color: #18A7B2;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="__applyingfor">
      <p id="__title">What Are You Applying For?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="__applyoptions">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="__apply-normal" src="../images/helperapp.png">
            <img class="__apply-hover" src="../images/helperapph.png">
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="__apply-normal" src="../images/modapp.png">
            <img class="__apply-hover" src="../images/modapph.png">
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="__apply-normal" src="../images/adminapp.png">
            <img class="__apply-hover" src="../images/adminapph.png">
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="__apply-normal" src="../images/devapp.png">
            <img class="__apply-hover" src="../images/devpph.png">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use 'display:inline-block' rather then 'display:flex'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `display: inline-flex;` or remove `display:flex;` in `.__applyoptions ul a{`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Join the Team</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    .__applyingfor {
      width: 500px;
      height: 150px;
      margin: auto auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .__applyoptions {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      
    }

    .__applyoptions ul{
      display: flex;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      background-size: cover;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .__applyoptions ul li{
      margin-right: 1px;
      
    }

    .__applyoptions ul a{
      display: inline-flex;
      position: relative;
    }

    .__apply-normal:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .__apply-hover {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .__apply-hover:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    #__title {
      font-size: 25px;
    }

    #__title:hover {
      color: #18A7B2;
    }
    
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="__applyingfor">
      <p id="__title">What Are You Applying For?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="__applyoptions">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="__apply-normal" src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
            <img class="__apply-hover" src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="__apply-normal" src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
            <img class="__apply-hover" src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="__apply-normal" src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
            <img class="__apply-hover" src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="__apply-normal" src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
            <img class="__apply-hover" src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Removed `display: flex;` from `__applyoptions ul a`. You need to `display:flex;` only to the container.

```css
.__applyingfor {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.__applyoptions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.__applyoptions ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 10px;
}

.__applyoptions ul li {
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.__applyoptions ul a {
  position: relative;
}

.__apply-normal:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.__apply-hover {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.__apply-hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#__title {
  font-size: 25px;
}

#__title:hover {
  color: #18A7B2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="__applyingfor">
    <p id="__title">What Are You Applying For?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="__applyoptions">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="__apply-normal" src="../images/helperapp.png">
          <img class="__apply-hover" src="../images/helperapph.png">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="__apply-normal" src="../images/modapp.png">
          <img class="__apply-hover" src="../images/modapph.png">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="__apply-normal" src="../images/adminapp.png">
          <img class="__apply-hover" src="../images/adminapph.png">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="__apply-normal" src="../images/devapp.png">
          <img class="__apply-hover" src="../images/devpph.png">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `float:left;` to the .__applyoptions ul a{} section:

```
.__applyoptions ul a{
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      float:left;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hewr1ku/)

Comment: Why use `float:left` when you can just do `display:inline-flex`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your li style with the following property:

```
.__applyoptions ul li { 
 margin-right: 1px;
 float: left;
 display: inline-flex;
}
```